# Twilio - call forwarding to a client - no application

Tags: twilio, call

I'm working with developers to build a Twilio application for some mobile staff but to cover our basic requirement I want the mobile staff to call a Twilio mobile number and Twilio then autodials a client and presents the Twilio number as the caller ID.

I want to use Studio flow for this and already managed to set up rules to autoforward calls to the staff member that would be the owner of the respective number.

What I want to know specifically is, can I add a function that the staff member calls a number as follows:
(Twilio-mobile + client-mobile)

Then Twilio recognizes that the call ID is the staff number and dials out the client-number.

I want to be able to do this without the staff member entering the clients phone number every time.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Gary

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Studio [Split Based on Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on) to check the From number, `trigger.call.From` is the staff members and if so, [call the client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/connect-call), otherwise call the staff.

There is a different approach using a Twilio Function for SMS instead of Voice in the below blog.

[Forwarding SMS and voice calls to an alternate phone number](https://www.twilio.com/blog/forwarding-sms-phone-calls-alternate-number)

Comment: Thanks. I've already got that far but want to know how do I pass the customers number as the number for Twilio to dial. The intent is to have the setup so I can use the same setup to call multiple customers. for example - if I dial 0412 3456 789  0478 945 689 i'd like Twilio to just dial out to 0478 945 689

Comment: You mean how to access some database for state of the mappings?